# How to change the about: pages in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

My PC was infected by the delta-homes nuisance yesterday.  I think as part of it, the about:navigationfailure, navigationcanceled, etc, have been redirected to various adware sites.

Where is the configuration for these pages?  The registry `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs` keys still show res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm, etc.

Comment: Why don't you just **Reset* IE and restore its settings by doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you managed to configure these pages back to normal? You can try [this guide](http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-delta-homes-com.html) that helped me several days ago to remove delta homes.. However, it consumed so much time and effort so that I would personally recommend installing Malwarebytes and running a scan

Comment: I reformatted my disk and re-installed Windows. I am disappointed that Microsoft allows programs that can be installed but **cannot be uninstalled**.